# code run correctly and print success message on console but not print in app

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

i am trying to send email to multiple person and i get the addresses from fire base and store them  in an array called department Emails, then i go through the array and send email to each address, the code work correctly and send all emails .my question is where in the code write agent.add("all email sent successfully") after sending all emails

```
function sendEmails(agent){
//ask for department number and subject and message
  var sub=agent.parameters.subject;
  var msg=agent.parameters.message;


  return getEmailsForDepartment(agent.parameters.departmentNO).then(function(){

    departmentEmails.forEach(function(email){
      return createMessagesForDepartment(sub,msg,email).then(()=>{
        console.log("email sent successfully");

      }).catch(()=>{
       console.log(`fail`);
      });

    })

  });
}// end of send emails

//this function to get all addresses from database 
function getEmailsForDepartment(numOFDepartment){

  var query = admin.database().ref("/"+departmentsNo[numOFDepartment]).orderByKey();
  return query.once("value").then(function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
      departmentEmails.push(childSnapshot.child('email').val());
    });

  });

}


function createMessagesForDepartment(sub,msg,emailAdd){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    // i promise to send email
    const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        user: '****@gmail.com',
        pass: '****'
      }
    });
    var mailOptions = {
      from: '*****@gmail.com',
      //how to send for all emails in array
      to: emailAdd, //receiver email
      subject: sub,
      text: msg
    };


    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);

        resolve('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      }
    });



  });


}//end of create message
```

Comment: Please, be nice with us and format your code properly!

Comment: I formatted the code properly, i hope you will find it well

Answer (score 0):

The `agent.add()` function doesn't work like `console.log()`. It doesn't send the message immediately to the user, and typically you can only send one message to the user. So I wouldn't expect it to print out three times.

If you need to see a message for each, build a string during the loop, and call `agent.add()` once with that built string.

Comment: I wouldn't need to print agent.add("success ") three times, i need to print one message after send all emails

Comment: Then you would want them after the `forEach()`

Comment: @Prisoner, there are asynchronous callbacks inside the forEach, so I don't think that works.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep a counter of the number of emails remaining to be sent.  Initialize this number with the number of department emails.  Then the callback for each email that is successfully sent will decrement this number.  When a callback observes that the number of emails remaining to be sent is zero, you can safely report that all emails have been sent.

```
return getEmailsForDepartment(agent.parameters.departmentNO).then(function(){

  // Initialize a counter here.
  let numberOfEmailsRemainingToSend = departmentEmails.length;

  departmentEmails.forEach(function(email){

    return createMessagesForDepartment(sub,msg,email).then(()=>{
      console.log("email sent successfully");

      // Decrement the counter here.
      if(!--numberOfEmailsRemainingToSend)) {
        // When the counter reaches zero, all tasks are complete.
        agent.add("all email sent successfully")
      } 

    }).catch(()=>{
      console.log(`fail`);
    });

  })

});
```